# jQuery.getJSON not working properly in IE8 with gdata json-c. Why?

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-8, getjson, gdata

Using jQuery:

```
$.getJSON('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/b2-5GSjZvW8?v=2&alt=jsonc', function(meta){alert(meta.data.title);});
```

Firefox and Chrome both work as expected, but IE keeps triggering the error function (when using `$.ajax`) instead of success. The error status is "0" which doesn't help much.

I've also tried using `$.ajax` with `cache:false` to no avail.

Any ideas?

Comment: I have heard that IE can be very aggressive in its caching; if you clear the cache and then try your code again, does it succeed?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I can't tell you if it's an error in jquery or IE, but it looks like the XDomainRequest fails in IE. Add this to the URL:

```
&callback=?
```

...so the response will be handled as jsonp.

**Edit:** It looks like Microsoft's [XDOmainRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288060%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is not implemented in jQuery, so you can't run Cross-Domain-Requests in jQuery using IE(except jsonp)

Comment: This answer just changed my life :)

Comment: Really! you saved me from goolging for another don't know how many days!!!