# jQuery -> getJSON -> Data load fail on outside server -> IE issue only <- All other browsers work

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

jQuery -> getJSON -> Data load fails on outside server.

This works fine on all other browsers but IE9.  I've set headers (active...origin:* etc) on the php script that delivers JSON data from the primary server.

What needs to happen to jQuery / getJSON to get IE to retrieve the data.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318996/jquery-getjson-not-working-properly-in-ie8-with-gdata-json-c-why/6320496#6320496

Comment: Adding callback=? is a no go for me; in fact, that kills all the browsers from sending requestion

Comment: IE get a ";" error too when adding the callback

Comment: A couple of things that you might already have checked but aren't mentioned above - is your server definitely returning a response? You might find that it's the server choking on something (headers, missing cookies?) specific to IE's request. Firebug or Fiddler useful here. Second, is there any chance the data you are passing is serializing to be greater than 2000+ characters in the GET url? Sounds unlikely but does happen. What happens if you POST?

Comment: I did some extensive research; I'm utilizing callback=? it seems that IE is recognizing the call (via console, before no net request were shown).  Utilizing callback=? prevents jquerys getJSON function(data) right? Cause I never get data back after the callback goes through

Comment: Is it even possible to utilize the follow up function(data) from jquerys getJSON when utilizing the callback? This is what I'd like to really do.  So far, with out the callback, it works in everything but I.E.; i've set the origin headers and etc (*); but IE is being the pain

Comment: I figured it out; in the incoming json you must set the call back name before the []($json->data); This really needs to be noted more clearer.

Answer (score 0):

try using JSONP

here is what you need to do in your php script

```
<?
$data = '{"name" : "hello world"}';
echo $_GET['jsoncallback'] . '(' . $data . ');';
?>
```

and in the url just add

```
&jsoncallback=?
```