# jQuery.getJSON() doesn't work properly in IE9 and below

Tags: jquery, ajax, youtube-api

```
var video_id='VA770wpLX-Q';

$.getJSON('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/'+video_id+'?v=2&alt=jsonc',function(data,status,xhr){
    alert(data.data.title);
});
```

I am having issue in using getJSON() in ie9 and below, the request is done but function is not running, it is working on all the other browsers except IE, already tested over different jquery versions still no luck, help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours googling and I found a simple and effective solution!

[jQuery.getJSON not working properly in IE8 with gdata json-c. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318996/jquery-getjson-not-working-properly-in-ie8-with-gdata-json-c-why)

Just add `&callback=?` to the end of your url string.

Answer (score 3):

Try this hack, it should make IE work with cross domain requests in this case:

```
$.support.cors = true;
$.getJSON('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/' + video_id + '?v=2&alt=jsonc', function (data) {
    console.log(data.data.title);
});
```

Worked for me http://jsbin.com/ariyec/1/

Comment: hmmm sorry I tested in ie8 and it doesn't work...I am wondering if I shouldn't use getJSON method, I am not familiar with ajax, any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

please use jsonp like this:

```
  var video_id='VA770wpLX-Q';

  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/'+video_id+'?v=2&alt=jsonc',
    success: function(data,status,xhr){alert(data.data.title);},
         dataType: 'jsonp'
  });
```