# AJAX request returning error code 0 in ie9 and below?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-maps

I have an ajax function in my script that works fine in all browsers except ie9 and below.

I've read elsewhere on Stackoverflow ([jQuery.getJSON not working properly in IE8 with gdata json-c. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318996/jquery-getjson-not-working-properly-in-ie8-with-gdata-json-c-why)) that this could be a cross domain issue but if it was that surely my code would fail in all browsers?

Can anybody provide me with some advice?

```
function GetLocation(location) {
    var result;
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + location + "&components=country:UK&sensor=false&callback=?",
        async: false,
        data: 'json',
        dataType: 'text json',
        success: function (data) {
            result = data;
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(xhr.status);
            alert(thrownError);
        }
    });

    return result;
}
```

Comment: You're best off using the native geocoding methods provided in Google maps Api for javascript, that gets around all that sh*t.

Comment: Might not be the problem, but just an idea; jQuery has 2 versions. Version 1.x is designed to run on old browsers. Version 2.x does not work for IE 6, 7, or 8. See details on their download page. http://jquery.com/download/

Comment: No luck @BaileyHerbert thanks for the advice though

Comment: When  you read it correctly somewhere(e.g. in the duplicate of this question/your previous question) then it should be clear that it's a browser-specific issue in jQuery which doesn't affect all browsers.

Comment: However, the geocoding-API did not specify the headers that will be sent, so you cant rely on the `access-control-allow-origin`-header. When no matching header will be sent(what happens often in the  past) the request will fail in all browsers, so it's strongly recommended to use the geocoder of the Javascript-API as suggested by Rob Schmuecker.

Comment: async false for a x-domain request? uson json datatype and a jsonp url parameter? things look pretty messed up with this request.